# Trigger jQuery event object on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

I have a simple CodeMirror-like set up, in which a parent div (transparent `<textarea>` within a `<label>`) overlays a `<pre>` element that can be highlighted etc. I want to be able to hover over elements in the `<pre>`, but also be able to click the `<textarea>` and edit it's contents. I.e. - by default, events should pass-through the `<label>` and apply to the output `<pre>`.

Is there any way to trigger an event after-the-fact? Specifically, trigger a jQuery **event object**, not just an event?

In this scenario, triggering a click on the textarea wouldn't be useful without it being in a specific location. I'd rather not extract the mouseEvent's x and y position, and map onto the textarea that way.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
output.bind('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    label.css('pointer-events', 'auto');
    
    //this isn't real
    event.target = label;
    event.apply();
});
label.bind('mouseup', function(event) {
    label.css('pointer-events', 'none')
});
```

If you can come up with something IE10 compatible (no pointer-events) that'd be even better.

Edit: had `label.trigger(event)`, but didn't properly reflect use case...

If there was a function opposite to `event.preventDefault()` - something like `event.triggerDefault()`, that's what I would want to trigger.

Comment: Hi, I want to understand your use case better. What is preventing you from doing label.trigger("myEvent", event) and then label.bind("myEvent", function(event) {....

Comment: so you want to trigger the mouseup event? `label.trigger('mouseup');` or you want to trigger the same event on a different object?

Comment: When you click a textarea, it puts your caret where you click. You can't do that by just triggering click() on the textarea.